# Symfony 2.7 custom exception handler

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use a custom controller for exception handling in my Symfony 2.7 project, but I'getting this error: `Type error: Too few arguments to function Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::__construct()`

I have set the exception class like this:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: MyProject\MainBundle\Controller\MyProjectExceptionController::showException
```

I know I have to configure a service to pass the correct arguments to the constructor. So I have the follwing configuration in config.yml:

```
services:
    myproject.twig.controller.exception: 
        class: MyProject\MainBundle\Controller\MyProjectExceptionController 
        arguments: [@twig, %kernel.debug%]
```

I have read many SO's answers on the subject and seen that there is some changes in this configuration between Symfony's versions. I've tried also `app.configuration_exception` and some other options.

Anyone knows what is the correct configuration specifically for Symfony 2.7 ?

**Edit**

Answering @Constantin:

Actually I was still doing initial tests. So I basically copied Twig's ExceptionControler, and stripped all but showAction and included a test environment variable in order to see if everything was working fine. This is the result:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
//use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
//use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface;
//use Twig\Environment;
//use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
//use Twig\Loader\ExistsLoaderInterface;

class MyProjectExceptionController extends ExceptionController {

    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering($request->headers->get('X-Php-Ob-Level', -1));
        $showException = $request->attributes->get('showException', $this->debug); // As opposed to an additional parameter, this maintains BC

        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();

        return new Response($this->twig->render(
            (string) $this->findTemplate($request, $request->getRequestFormat(), $code, $showException),
            array(
                'status_code' => $code,
                'status_text' => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
                'exception' => $exception,
                'logger' => $logger,
                'currentContent' => $currentContent,
                'test' => "TEST"
            )
            ), 200, array('Content-Type' => $request->getMimeType($request->getRequestFormat()) ?: 'text/html'));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your MyProjectExceptionController  plz?

Comment: @Constantin included the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have a little mistake in

```
twig:
    exception_controller: MyProject\MainBundle\Controller\MyProjectExceptionController::showException
```

That line should be "showAction" and not "showException".
But I cannot confirm that it will solve the issue.

As you are extending "ExceptionController", the definition of the service should be fine and will match the constructor. But it is better to put services definitions in services.yml

Can you run this command and try to find your service in it (to be sure it's there) :

```
php app/console debug:container
```

[EDIT] Ok just read the doc and we can read :

> In case of extending the ExceptionController you may configure a service to pass the Twig environment and the debug flag to the constructor. *** And then configure twig.exception_controller using the controller as services syntax (e.g.  app.exception_controller:showAction).

In your case it would give:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: myproject.twig.controller.exception:showAction
```

I guess this one should solve your issue...
Please try and let me know the result.

PS: doc is available [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller)

Comment: using this command I saw 2 related services: `myproject.twig.controller.exception` pointing to `MyProject\MainBundle\Controller\MyProjectExceptionController` and `twig.controller.exception` pointing to the original file `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController`

Comment: It seems to work... just a min, I'm trying to understand what's happening here.

Comment: It was a pleasure for me to help you in unblocking the situation.